# How to implement the selection of contours on the image using neural networks?

Tags: python

I have an image and I need to implement the outline selection of the image on it.

I achieved this implementation by using

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("E:\map3.png")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
kernel = np.array([[0, 1, 1], [-1, 0, 1], [-1, -1, 0]])
koch = cv2.filter2D(gray, -1, kernel)
thresh = cv2.threshold(koch, 100, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cv2.drawContours(img, contours, -1, (0, 0, 255), 2)
cv2.imshow('koh', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I have researched many pages on the Internet, but they either use trained models that either do not work for me, or give the wrong result, and I do not know how to implement pre-training.

who knows what neural networks exist for the possible selection of contours in the image, or how can training be implemented and a working neural network be made?